# How Do We Connect Corda To Azure PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, azure, corda

I am trying to connect Corda 4.1 (open source) to Azure PostgreSQL.

With the following in the node.conf:

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://my-dev-corda-db.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/banks"
    dataSource.user = "me@my-dev-corda-db"
    dataSource.password = Password
}
```

It throws the error:

```
[ERROR] 2019-08-08T23:44:45,301Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.: Could not connect to the
database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database. [errorCode=uz1y94, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.1/uz1y94]
net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CouldNotCreateDataSourceException: Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.
....
....
Suppressed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
...
```

So I add `ssl=true` to the url:

```
dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://my-dev-corda-db.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/banks?ssl=true"
```

and it throws the error:

```
[ERROR] 2019-08-08T23:49:45,409Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.: Could not connect to the
database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database. [errorCode=17q5mal, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.1/17q5mal]
net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CouldNotCreateDataSourceException: Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.
...
...
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Could not open SSL root certificate file /home/corda/.postgresql/root.crt.
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL root certificate file /home/corda/.postgresql/root.crt.
...
```

I then tried setting the `sslmode=require`:

```
dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://my-dev-corda-db.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/banks?ssl=true&sslmode=require"
```

which then errors with:

```
[ERROR] 2019-08-08T23:53:38,323Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.: Could not connect to the
database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database. [errorCode=uz1y94, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.1/uz1y94]
net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CouldNotCreateDataSourceException: Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.
...
...
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "57.211.24.3", user "me", database "banks", SSL on
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:512) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "57.211.24.3", user "me", database "banks", SSL on
...
```

What are the full correct steps to use Azure PostgreSQL with Corda?

Answer (score 1):

When you connect from Internet to Azure PostgreSQL you need to enable your IP in the server's firewall, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-firewall-rules#connecting-from-the-internet.

You can do it simply from Azure portal - go to `Connection Security` and `Add Client IP` (if you don't have a static IP, then you need to repeat it each time).

For JDBC connection settings only `?sslmode=require` is needed, so in your node configuration use:

```
dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://my-dev-corda-db.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/banks?sslmode=require"
```